# How to scrape a word from href html

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

my code is:

```
url = "https://www.example.html"
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
result = soup.find("div", class_="d-flex align-items-center")
```

Ant it gives me the following html code:

```
<div class="d-flex align-items-center">
 <a href="../p/p.php?id=90">
  <img class="mr-1" src="../../i/em/89.png"/>
 </a>
 <a href="../p/p.php?id=90">
  Europe
 </a>
</div>
```

My goal is to scrape `Europe` but I do not know how to do it.

Comment: Is this works for you `result.findAll('a')[1].contents[0]`?

Comment: @Charnel it gives me this error: `"ResultSet object has no attribute '%s'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?" % key
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'findAll'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
url = "https://www.example.html"
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
someHTML = soup.find("div", class_="d-flex align-items-center")
result = someHTML.findAll('a')[1].contents[0]
```

Should work.

Like @Charnel said

Edit:

I have tested the approach with:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

exampleHTML = '''
<div class="d-flex align-items-center">
 <a href="../p/p.php?id=90">
  <img class="mr-1" src="../../i/em/89.png"/>
 </a>
 <a href="../p/p.php?id=90">
  Europe
 </a>
</div> 
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(exampleHTML, 'html.parser')

print(soup.findAll('a')[1].contents[0])
```

Which perfectly outputs `Europe` as expected.